# Python - Create multiple lists and zip

Tags: python, list, for-loop, zip

I am looking to produce multiple lists based on the same function which randomises data based on a list. I want to be able to easily change how many of these new lists I want to have and then combine. The code which creates each list is the following:

```
    """ 
    """
    R_ensemble=[]
    for i in range(0,len(R)):
        if R[i]==0:
            R_ensemble.append(0)
        else:
            R_ensemble.append(np.random.normal(loc=R[i],scale=R[i]/4,size=None)) 
    return R_ensemble
```

This perturbs each value from the list based on a normal distribution.

To combine them is fine when I just want a handful of lists:

```
    """
    """
    ensemble_form_1,ensemble_form_2,ensemble_form_3 = [],[],[]
    
    ensemble_form_1 = normal_transform(R)
    ensemble_form_2 = normal_transform(R)
    ensemble_form_3 = normal_transform(R)

    zipped_ensemble = list(zip(ensemble_form_1,ensemble_form_2,ensemble_form_3))
    df_ensemble = pd.DataFrame(zipped_ensemble, columns = ['Ensemble_1', 'Ensemble_2','Ensemble_3'])
    
    return ensemble_form_1, ensemble_form_2, ensemble_form_3
```

How could I repeat the same randomisation process to create a fixed number of lists (say 50 or 100), and then combine them into a table? Is there an easy way to do this with a for loop, or any other method? I'd need to be able to pick out each new list/column individually, as I would be combining the results in some way.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can construct multiple lists and a table like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Your function for creating the individual lists
def normal_transform(R):
    R_ensemble=[]
    for i in range(0,len(R)):
        if R[i]==0:
            R_ensemble.append(0)
        else:
            R_ensemble.append(np.random.normal(loc=R[i],scale=R[i]/4,size=None))
    return R_ensemble

# Construction of multiple lists and the dataframe
NUM_LISTS = 50
R = list(range(100))

data = dict()
for i in range(NUM_LISTS):
    data['Ensemble_' + str(i)] = normal_transform(R)
df_ensemble = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

You can access the individual lists/ columns like this:

```
df_ensemble['Ensemble_42']
df_ensemble[df_ensemble.columns[42]]
```

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted, after removing the line R = list(range(100)). Thank you very much

Comment: Glad it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `zip()` with `*` to create dataframe with variable number of columns. For example:

```
import pandas as pd


def generate_list(n):
    #... generate your list here
    return [*range(n)]

def get_dataframe(n_columns, n):
    return pd.DataFrame(zip(*[generate_list(n) for _ in range(n_columns)]), columns=['Ensemble_{}'.format(i) for i in range(1, n_columns+1)])

print(get_dataframe(8, 10))
```

Prints (8 columns, 10 rows):

```
   Ensemble_1  Ensemble_2  Ensemble_3  Ensemble_4  Ensemble_5  Ensemble_6  Ensemble_7  Ensemble_8
0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0
1           1           1           1           1           1           1           1           1
2           2           2           2           2           2           2           2           2
3           3           3           3           3           3           3           3           3
4           4           4           4           4           4           4           4           4
5           5           5           5           5           5           5           5           5
6           6           6           6           6           6           6           6           6
7           7           7           7           7           7           7           7           7
8           8           8           8           8           8           8           8           8
9           9           9           9           9           9           9           9           9
```